# Android Location Listener (or Android Events in general)

Tags: android

I have a general question about LocationListener in Android. Perhaps this is about Android or Java events in general, but not sure.

There seems to be a million ways to set up a LocationListener, and they all seem pretty ugly (mainly because of lack of reusability). Here is an example from android found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html):

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

This works, but, I'm really surprised that this is a standard way of writing OOP code...

What I would really like to see is a simple a *reusable* way to implement LocationListener. Anybody know of a simple tutorial on how this could be done? My goal would be to be able to implement this easily any Activities that need to be updated with gps information... perhaps a Service? Thanks!